# How to disable a device in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have my internal keyboard on my laptop which is broken and keeps typing random letters.

I have an external keyboard which I use and is working perfectly.

Can you help me disable the internal keyboard? (permanently)

Comment: Which windows version are you using is it home/pro and the version .Any ways try this : https://thegeekpage.com/disable-laptop-keyboard-permanently/  and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to device manager and search for keyboards and under keyboards find your laptop's keyboard and disable it or you can press uninstall device.